# Select the rows with most available information in a data frame with R

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to select the rows with the highest number of information in a data frame. This data frame is generated automaticaly so the name of columns increase over the time.

the data are like.

```
Player  V1  F1  V2  F2  V3  F3  V4  F4
111111  0   0   1   3   0   0   1   3
111111  0   0   1   3   1   3   1   3
222222  3   4   0   0   3   4   3   4
222222  3   4   3   4   3   4   3   4
33333   1   2   1   2   1   2   1   2
33333   1   2   1   2   1   2   0   0
```

and it should be:

```
Player  V1  F1  V2  F2  V3  F3  V4  F4
111111  0   0   1   3   1   3   1   3
222222  3   4   3   4   3   4   3   4
33333   1   2   1   2   1   2   1   2
```

the idea is to select the rows with the most complete information.
I'm considering 0 as incomplete information

Comment: Why is row 2 kept, but row 3 is dropped? Don't both of them have two 0s? What is your definition of " the most complete information." Please include this in your question, rather than in the comments.

Comment: What do you mean by "most complete information"? Are looking to minimize the number of zeroed entries? Do you have an absolute threshold in mind or should the non-zero entry percentage be higher than the median?

Comment: Two people are trying to answer your unclear question.  Two people have asked for clarification in the comments.  You haven't responded to anything.  -1 and voting to close this question.

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned the data frame is generated automatically so the name of columns increase over the time. Is it real time grouping you are trying to do ?

This data.table approach below should be good to group the Player column accordingly and select the max value. It works for the representative example you gave. 
This is similar to the answer provided @arun here. [Group by one column, select row with minimum in one column for every pair of columns in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37531014/group-by-one-column-select-row-with-minimum-in-one-column-for-every-pair-of-col/37532078#37532078)

```
require (data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(df)
# Get the column names
my_cols <- c("V1","F1","V2","F2","V3","F3","V4","F4")  

# Map applies function and subset across all the columns passed
# as vector my_cols, and mget return value of the named object

# data.table expression written in general form for understanding DT[i, j, by]
# missing i implies "on all rows".
# this expression computes the expression in 'j' grouped by 'Player'
dt[, Map(`[`, mget(my_cols), lapply(mget(my_cols), which.max)), by = Player]
#    Player V1 F1 V2 F2 V3 F3 V4 F4
# 1: 111111  0  0  1  3  1  3  1  3
# 2: 222222  3  4  3  4  3  4  3  4
# 3:  33333  1  2  1  2  1  2  1  2
```

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out by @Imo and @evan058, it's not clear what "most complete information" means. I assume you consider a `0` to be missing information, consequently that "most complete" refers to the entry with the least `0` entries per player:

This snippet should do the job then:

```
library(plyr)
newData <- ldply(unique(data$Player), function(player) {
  tmp <- data[data$Player == player,]
  tmp[which.max(rowSums(tmp[,-1] != 0)),]
})
print(newData)
```

Comment: This is only appropriate if the numbers indiate the amount of information. If anything but 0 is a single datum the which clause needs to `rowSum(tmp != 0)`

Comment: @robin-gertenbach very good point, I implicitly assumed information to just be added (in which case this would work out as well), but never be *updated* by replacing an already existing, non-zero value. Snippet updated.